# Mounting an NFS share to the current user

Tags: mount, permissions, nfs, share

I have two Raspberry Pis, say Pi-One and Pi-Two. I have an NFS share setup on Pi-One. I have 2 users on Pi-Two, the original 'Pi' (uid=1000, gid=1000), and 'Steve' (uid=1001, gid=1001).
Whatever I do when mounting the NFS share on Pi-Two, user 'Pi' is always the owner of the mounted directory. I have tried almost infinite changes to /etc/exports and mount and yet nothing I do results in 'Steve' owning the mapped directory, and hence being able to use it.
Much of what I have researched appears to involve apparently complicated processes, which stretch my computing abilities somewhat! Surely what I'm trying to do is as basic as it gets in sharing a resource between two computers?
Any help or advise would be very much appreciated.
showmount -e on Pi-Two flags up the correct share
The owner of the shared folder on Pi-One is NOT 'Pi' (there is no user 'Pi' on Pi-One!)
There is no user 'Steve' on Pi-One - Does there need to be? If so would he need the same uid & gid (and if so how would that be engineered?).
I have seen references to running Kerberos and editing dhcp.conf and the like, which I am up for if that's what it takes but I would need a step by step guide to achieve success.

Comment: Please edit yr Q & add the mounting details - and maybe read a [how-to on NFS](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-an-nfs-share-in-linux/).

Comment: And try writing in paragraphs; when I see a block of text my brain freezes.